# Is it possible to cookie the state of the expand/collapse button from the jqGrid header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com) and I can't find a way to save the state of the expand/collapse button on the top right of the header using cookies.

On my page I have 10 jqGrid's and it would be nice to save the hidden state of the grid.

Comment: If I correctly understand your requirements then you need just use `hiddengrid` option in every grid and to use the values of the option based on the value from the cookie/`localStorage`. If `hiddengrid: true` is used then the grid will be created in collapsed state. You can use `onHeaderClick` to save/modify the saved value of the state in the cookie/`localStorage`. One more parameter `gridstate` could be helpful for you too. It has the value `"visible"` or `"hidden"` depend on the current state.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using `localStorage` to save the state in client-side (i.e. in the browser)

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
result = localStorage.getItem("lastname"); 
}
```

There are various resources available in the internet for reference and further reading on it.